# Free Level Meter Plug-in

Tags: plug-ins

I am using Protools LE 8 M-box 2 Pro and I want to do some mixing but I see there is no Level meter that is included in the package. And I don't have enough moolas to buy the DV TOOLKIT 2. Does anyone know where I can Download a level meter for Protools le 8 for free it need not even be fancy?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Sonalksis FreeG](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317233115/http://www.sonalksis.com:80/freeg.htm):

[image]
<sub>(source: [sonalksis.com](http://www.sonalksis.com/images/freeg.gif))</sub>

RTAS, VST and Audio Unit

Mac and Windows

And best of all: Free!

Answer (score 2):

check your plug-in list, "sound field" category i believe, and see if you have the "PhaseScope" plug-in. it's a multi-channel type plug-in, so you can't run it on a mono track, that you can only instantiate on a track (no audiosuite). i can't remember if it's included with the digirack plugins in 8 LE (i believe it is), but that should suit your needs if it's there.

Comment: PhaseScope is available right out of the box with Pro Tools 8 LE.

Comment: @Justin - Thanks for the confirmation. Have had CPTK for a while now, but figured PhaseScope was digirack. @Wesley - it provides a number of different metering scales and behaviors which are very useful (LEQA being one of them).

Answer (score 2):

I came across this freeware plugin yesterday. It's by Flux and called Stereo Tool. Going to give it a bash next week.

http://www.fluxhome.com/products/freewares/stereotool

Comment: + Stereo Tool is fantastic, I've been using it for a few years now.  It's my go-to stereo width tool and seems to do a more transparent job to my ears than the Waves S1 (although the S1 has a great ability to play with the skew).  Also, the Phasescope on StereoTool is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.smassey.com/plugin.html - couldn't do without HR Meter really.
+
http://brianleewhite.com/2009/11/04/metering-with-digirack-phasescope/

Comment:  
 I also use that free Massey meter as well in my home studio. I feel it gives a much better graphic display as opposed to the built in PAZ-Meter. It doesn't take up much screen real estate either and you can place it above your session window as it runs horizontally. 
 

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones listed, I really like the free version of [RNS Inspector](http://www.rndigital.com/inspector.html). Its meters aren't as big as the HR meter, but I find the spectral analysis tool handy for sound design and mixing.

Comment: I used to absolutely LOVE this plug, but I lost it when I got a new computer and you can't get it anymore! 

Answer (score 0):

Check this site out, you'll probably find what you need ... http://www.darkwood.demon.co.uk/PC/meter.html

Comment: this is a really cool page thanks for sharing !!

Answer (score 0):

I know that because my suggestion is a part of DVTK, it's somewhat of a moot point, but I thought I'd mention it as an answer to the broader question of a "free" metering plugin.

TLMasterMeter is a great little gem I discovered recently and it's one of my go-to's.  It is highly accurate (displays the exact same levels on repeat transient playback unlike PhaseScope which has been dodgy in my experience), and it also shows the meter level readout at 8x oversampling.  Another great featrue on it is that it has an event log for meter clipping (which I believe is in the same vain as the paid version RND Inspector).  If there's one thing lacking from this though, is that the event time values are displayed as min/sec from the start of playback, instead of reading the SMPTE from the session and showing that.  Maybe there's a way to do it and I just can't find it.  If Avid fixes that, the plugin in gold.

I only use PhaseScope when I need to monitor a master output bus for Leq(A) loudness metering.  For mission-critical accuracy and QC, refer to TLMasterMeter

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of great, free meter plugins available.

- HOFA: 4U Meter (this one is great)
- Melda Productions: MLoudness (this one comes with their Freeware pack, and they are some of the best free plugins available. Period.)
- Klanghelm: VUMT (this is my personal favorite and go-to for metering. It's not technically free, but $10 USD is pretty doggone close. Check out his other plugins as well - he's got some good things going on.)